# Aurelia - Combine json from two API calls into one

Tags: json, aurelia

I have an Aurelia web app that searches an artist by name then returns all of the works of art by the artist.  The json returned by the artist search looks similar to this:

```
{
"source": "Museum",
"language": "EN",
"resultsCount": 1,
"objects": [
  {
  "objectNumber": "125.1988",
  "objectID": 981,
  "title": "Governor's Palace (Raj Bhaven) project, Chandigarh, India",
  "displayName": "Le Corbusier (Charles-Édouard Jeanneret)",
  "alphaSort": "Le Corbusier (Charles-Édouard Jeanneret)",
  "artistID": 3426,
  "displayDate": "French, born Switzerland. 1887–1965",
  "dated": "1951–1976",
  "dateBegin": 1951,
  "dateEnd": 1976,
  "medium": "Wood, cardboard, and plexiglass",
  "dimensions": "33 x 71 1/4 x 65\" (83.8 x 181 x 165.1 cm)",
  "department": "Architecture & Design",
  "classification": "A&D Architectural Model",
  "onView": 0,
  "provenance": "",

  etc....
```

The full json is here:

https://github.com/smoore4moma/tms-api/blob/master/object.json

The problem I have is that the artist search can return multiple artists with the similar names ("Serra" for example returns Richard Serra and Daniel Serra-Badué).  So I can loop through the search and call the API twice to get the works of art, but I have not found a way to combine the two different API calls, not with Aurelia anyway.  Here is a code snippet of what I am trying to do.  I've tried jQuery, .extend, .concat, .push, creating arrays, dictionary....I'm just stuck.

```
    getByConstituentId(id) {
    return this.http.fetch(baseUrl + "/artists/" + id + token)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        return response.objects;
    });
    }

// This is not the actual looping code.  But the idea is to combine these two function calls into one result and return that.

     getBySearchTerms(searchCreator) {

     let obj0 = this.getByConstituentId(5350); 
     let obj1 = this.getByConstituentId(5349); 

     return ???  // This is where I am looking for help.
                 // just for ex. "return this.getByConstituentId(5349);" 
                 // works just fine

     }
```

Any advice on how to do this?  Otherwise, I am going to build an API method that take an array of artist IDs, but I'd rather have simple API methods and combine json where needed. Thanks.

**FOLLOW-UP**

Following @Tomalak advice, this is eventually what worked:

```
   return Promise.all([
   this.getByConstituentId(5349),
   this.getByConstituentId(5350)])
   .then(response => {

     return response[0].concat(response[1]);

    });
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see constant comments about not posting urls because it may turn into a dead link some day...so which is it??

Comment: Post code as text, obviously.

Comment: Ah. That makes perfect sense.  I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`Promise.all()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

> [...] returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

```
function getByConstituentId(id) {
    return this.http.fetch(baseUrl + "/artists/" + id + token)
    .then(response => response.json().objects);
};

function getBySearchTerms(searchCreator) {
    return Promise.all([
        this.getByConstituentId(5350),
        this.getByConstituentId(5349)
    ]);
}
```

If jQuery actually does your Ajax calls (i.e. if `this.http.fetch` is a wrapper around `$.ajax`) you can use jQuery's [`jquery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), which fulfills the same purpose but makes you independent of [the browser's native support for the Promise API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises).

```
function getBySearchTerms(searchCreator) {
    return $.when(
        this.getByConstituentId(5350),
        this.getByConstituentId(5349)
    );
}
```

Note the differing call conventions. `$.when` expects an argument list, while `Promise.all()` expects an iterable (like an array).

You can use `$.when` with an array argument through `.apply()`.

```
function getBySearchTerms(searchCreator) {
    return $.when.apply($, [
        this.getByConstituentId(5350),
        this.getByConstituentId(5349)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This looks very "promising."  Testing now and not getting an error, but not getting expected result either.  Will get back to you soon.

Comment: `getBySearchTerms` returns another promise. Use the return value accordingly.